# Can Decrypt[] be forced to decrypt with a different key?

Tags: cryptography

`Decrypt[]` will yield an error if one tries to decrypt a byte array using a different symmetric key than the one used to encrypt:

```
Decrypt[key2, Encrypt[key1, "foobar"]["Data"]]
> [..] Decrypt: Data could not be decrypted
> $Failed
```

I want to be able to mathematically perform the decrypt operation on a byte array and get a byte array even if the key doesn't match, for example, in [3DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES). How can I force `Decrypt` to not yield a message and return the "decrypted" bytes? How does it even know that the decryption is correct or not with no knowledge of the plaintext bytes?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Encrypt[key,"string"] yields an EncryptedObject containing the encrypted version of the contents of the string as encoded in UTF-8.

So the decrypted string must be valid UTF-8. However:

> Encrypt[key,ByteArray[...]] yields an EncryptedObject containing the encrypted version of the raw bytes in the ByteArray object.

so if the encrypted thing is a ByteArray, it may work.

Comment: Nope, if you pass a ByteArray output from Encrypt[] it still fails: `cryptMethod = <|"Cipher" -> "DES", "BlockMode" -> "ECB", 
   "InitializationVector" -> None|>;
Decrypt[GenerateSymmetricKey[Method -> cryptMethod], 
 ByteArray[{77, 232, 217, 172, 56, 169, 190, 202}]]`

Comment: Anyone know how to make this work?  I see the same thing that the ByteArray passing doesn't change that it still "fails".  There must be a checksum or something in addition to the encrypted data that is failing on the decryption.